# Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: php, oracle, xampp

I am getting this error when I start my xampp server.

> C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I downloaded `php_oci8-2.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86` and extracted `php_oci8.dll` into `C:\xampp\php\ext` directory.

Also, I downloaded `instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0` (32 bit version) and added the same to the PATH variable of windows.

`C:\OracleBasicClient\instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0\instantclient_12_1` added to PATH

Still, I'm getting this error and not sure why it is coming.

My windows is 64 bit.

PHP info (xampp)

**System**  Windows NT 6.1 (Windows 7 Professional) i586 
**Compiler**    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) 
**Architecture**    x86 
**Thread Safety**   enabled

What am I possibly doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows a built-type mismatch.

Resolve it by following these steps:

Make sure you download and install oracle **instantclient** at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html, but note:

1. Take note of your **Oracle** database version; use **Version 12.1.x** for Oracle database **12c** and **Version 11.1.x** for **11g** releases.
2. In either case, make sure you download the **Basic Lite** version of the Oracle instantclient.

After that, do add location of your Oracle instantclient to your System variable Path under your Environment Variables. Do equally ensure that you have both the PHP of your **xampp** and its **ext** available and set there as well (if not, do add them).

Then, proceed to add a new System variable with **TNS_ADMIN** as *variable name* and **the location to Oracle instantclient** as *variable value*.

Also, define your User variables *PATH* with the same **the location to Oracle instantclient** as *value*.

After this stage, restart your computer for a full propagation of the newly defined environment variables.

Once on, you may open your *Windows Command Prompt* and run **where oci*** to ensure that you had your environment variables well defined; the response should look like this:

```
C:\Users\flex>where oci*

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\oci.dll
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\ocijdbc11.dll
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\ocijdbc11.sym
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\ociw32.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\oci.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\oci.sym
C:\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.sym
C:\instantclient_11_2\ociw32.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\ociw32.sym
```

If not, your must have missed something and need to revisit the process, ensuring to completing it effectively.

You may now proceed to your php.ini file (provided environment variables are well defined) and enable your **oci** extensions (php_oci8.dll and php_oci8_11g.dll) by uncommenting them; you can achieve that by simply removing the semi column (**;**) before the said extensions.

Do remember to save your php.ini file, then, restart or start your apache if it isn't already running.

To check your PHP oci8 configurations are enabled, you may go back to your Windows Command Prompt and run: **php --ri oci8**; the response should be similar to the one below:

```
C:\Users\flex>php --ri oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.1.1
Revision => $Id: 86f22a208f89dcd5b305e82929a7429683968b11 $
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 11.2.0.4.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 10.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.events => Off => Off

Statistics =>
Active Persistent Connections => 0
Active Connections => 0
```

Alternatively, you can create a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` as content, then open it in your browser and search for oci8 occurrences; it should show enabled there as well.

Comment: I have done all steps and still receiving the warning and not connected with Oracle `$ php --ri oci8
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_
oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: @WaqasMehmood: Look inside your `C:\xampp\php\ext` directory and check for the file by name *php_ oci8_12c.dll*; can you locate it (the file)? I'm sure it must be missing. Is that the case please?

Comment: yes `php_oci8_12c.dll` file placed inside the `c:\xampp\php\ext` folder.

Comment: @WaqasMehmood: What version of *instantclient* are you using? Windows version? PHP version?

Comment: oracle Instant Client : instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0, php 7.1, windows 10, xampp 3.2.2

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @WaqasMehmood My Windows Version is Windows 10 64-bit, my PHP is 5.3.29, my Oracle InstaClient is instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip at 32-bit. The path variable is set correctly, so is the extension_dir variable. All other modules can be loaded correctly, this one is the only one throwing this not found error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you downloaded the DLL for a different architecture and pointed to it in your `php.ini`, instead of using the bundled DLL and simply un-commenting the default entry in `php.ini`.

I just downloaded the same version, XAMPP 3.2.2 x86, with PHP 7.1, and it **ships** with the DLL file that you need, which is installed to `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll`.

You appear to have done everything else correctly.

To fix the issue, ensure that the effective `php.ini` (by default, `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`) references *only* the default file (remove the erroneous entry you added for `php_oci8.dll`), like so:

```
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
```

Restart Apache and the problem should be resolved.