# Symfony 3 Using Behat without Entity - No Database Connection

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, behat

I'm using Symfony 3 with Behat 3 and an Oracle Database. Due to some circumstances i nee the possibility to directly write oracle sql code.

I'm stuck on the following error

> -- \AppBundle\Features\Context\UserSetupContext.php "Fatal error: Undefined constant 'OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS' 
>   (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)

First i thought that this would be caused because the oci extension is missing in php.ini. But it is enabled and can be used in a controller / command environment withing the same project.

So I'm thinking that the database connection is not connected, but i cannot find the problem. Please help.

Files:

```
<?php
-- \AppBundle\Features\Context\UserSetupContext.php
namespace AppBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;                    

class UserSetupContext implements Context
{

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    private $db;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    /**
     * @Given there are Users with the following details:
     */
    public function thereAreUsersWithTheFollowingDetails(TableNode $users)
    {
        foreach ($users->getColumnsHash() as $value) {
            // Test SQL
            $query = "INSERT INTO IT_MONITORING.USERS (
                           ID
                           , firstname
                           , lastname
                           , username
                           , password
                           , email
                           , status_id)
                        VALUES (
                           :id 
                           , :firstname
                           , :lastname
                           , :username
                           , :password
                           , :email
                           , 1)";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $query->bindValue("id", $value['id'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue("firstname", $value['firstname'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue("lastname", $value['lastname'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue("username", $value['username'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue("password", password_hash($value['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue("email", $value['email'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result = $query->execute();

            VarDumper::dump($result);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Config

```
--\behat.yml
default:

  suites:
    default:
      type: symfony_bundle
      bundle: AppBundle
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext:
            doctrine: "@doctrine"
        - AppBundle\Features\Context\UserSetupContext:
            db: "@doctrine.dbal.test_connection"

  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension:
      kernel:
        env: "dev"
        debug: "true"
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: "http://url"
      sessions:
        defaults:
          symfony2: ~
```

Comment: Found the answer myself. Ok i've created the problem myself, too... IDE was PHP-Storm and code "vendor\bin\behat" uses the local XAMPP environment.
Everything work on the external server, but the code won't work locally. Fix was to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38420665/1953421